# How to disable Skype social messages?

Tags: skype

Now Skype (version 7) also wants to be Facebook:

[image]

**Is there a way to disable these social messages?**
I think I've gone through all options, but I can't find it.

Comment: You can just forget them as they aren't actually posted to any social network (and are purely client side, it just "listens" for your contacts to change their mood message and aggregates that info in the "home" tab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. The cost of "free".